How to show annotated pdfs using PDFRenderer? (Android 15)
The below code works well for PDFs without annotations. Now, I'm looking to enhance this to support annotated PDFs as mentioned in the Android 15 Developer Preview release notes. But the annotated text isn't being displayed.
        val params = RenderParams.Builder(RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY)
            .setRenderFlags(FLAG_RENDER_HIGHLIGHT_ANNOTATIONS).build()
        
        page.render(bitmap, null, null, params)
        Image(bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(), contentDescription = null)

Here's a sample annotated pdf - here
Full code:
@RequiresApi(35)
@Composable
fun PdfViewer(uri: Uri, context: Context) {
    val pdfRenderer = remember { mutableStateOf<PdfRenderer?>(null) }
    val currentPage = remember { mutableStateOf<PdfRenderer.Page?>(null) }

    LaunchedEffect(uri) {
        currentPage.value?.close()
        pdfRenderer.value?.close()
        context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")?.let {
            pdfRenderer.value = PdfRenderer(it)
            currentPage.value = pdfRenderer.value?.openPage(0)
        }
    }

    currentPage.value?.let { page ->
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(page.width*3, page.height*3, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null)

        val params = RenderParams.Builder(RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY)
            .setRenderFlags(FLAG_RENDER_TEXT_ANNOTATIONS).build()

        page.render(bitmap, null, null, params)
        Image(bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(), contentDescription = null)
    }

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            currentPage.value?.close()
            pdfRenderer.value?.close()
        }
    }
}


What happens when displaying an annotated PDF? And how does that differ from your exxpectations?

@dan1st The text "this pdf is annotated" in the sample pdf I've linked isn't displayed when rendering it using PDFRenderer.
